# Get-AzVM data disk total size with Azure powershell cmdlets

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am working on an Azure Powershell script to pull some data. I want to get the total disk data size of the VM. Can someone help with this?

```
$virtualM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceName
    foreach ($vmachine in $virtualM) {
        #Get VM Name and Total data disk size
        write-host 'VM NAME: '$vmachine.name 'Data disk total size: '$vmachine.StorageProfile.dataDisks.diskSizeGB
        
    }
```

> ```
> #current output 
> VM NAME: VM1 Datadisk total size: 1023
> VM NAME: VM2 Datadisk total size: 1023 1023 1023
>
> #what I am trying to get
> VM NAME: VM1 Datadisk total size: 1023
> VM NAME: VM2 Datadisk total size: 3069
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$virtualM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceName
    foreach ($vmachine in $virtualM) {
        #Get VM Name and Total data disk size
        $disksum = $vmachine.StorageProfile.dataDisks.diskSizeGB | Measure-Object -Sum | select Sum -ExpandProperty SUM
        write-host 'VM NAME: '$vmachine.name 'Data disk total size: '$disksum
        
    }
```

> VM NAME:  1111 Data disk total size:  100
> VM NAME:  2222 Data disk total size:  2048
> VM NAME:  3333 Data disk total size:  7576
> VM NAME:  4444 Data disk total size:  7376
> VM NAME:  5555 Data disk total size:  7320